# Getting list index out of range when trying to print out JSON list element [data][i]name[1]value

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write a couple values out to a CSV from a JSON file, but getting a  index out of range error.

When I print the line, it works, but not in the for loop. This works:

```
print(data["macros"][0]["actions"][1]["value"])
```

but not this:

```
#Import the list of email addresses from a file
json_data=open('macros.json').read()

data = json.loads(json_data)

print "Number of macros:" + str(numbers) + "\n"

for n in range(0, numbers):

        print "\nN at top of loop: " + str(n) + "\n"

            name = (data["macros"][n]["title"])
            comment = (data["macros"][n]["actions"][1]["value"])

            print "\nN: " + str(n) + "\n"

            line = "'"+ name + "','" + comment + "'\n"

        print line
            file.write(line)

        #Now go back to the for loop and grab another macro to write out
            print "\nN at bottom: " + str(n) + ":\n"   
    file.close
```

What's interesting is that it does print out the first title and value of record 0, but when it gets to 1, I get that error:

```
N at top of loop: 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./import-json.py", line 55, in <module>
    comment = (data["macros"][n]["actions"][1]["value"])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I print out the second item in the actions list?

Comment: Hi this means that your when n = 1 , you have a missing element. In this case it is your list in  data["macros"][n]["actions"] i

Comment: Yes, that's correct although I was a bit confused. I needed to iterate on the actions list first, then grab the correct list element.
`for action in data["macros"][n]["actions"]:`

Answer (score 0):

data["macros"][n]["actions"] is a list, but with a variable number of elements.

To fix it, I need to iterate over that array and then grab the correct value.

```
for action in data["macros"][n]["actions"]:
#do stuff here
```